# How can I store price of something for every day of the year in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am working on a project but a have a problem with designing of database.
I need to store the price of something for every day in the year but i need to be able to change the prices for specific day.

Do i need to create a column for every day, in this approach i must create 365 columns in the table.

Do you have any better solution to this problem, any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: No, not unless you're just picking numbers out of a hat when deciding the price for any given day. I'm sure you've got some kind of algorithm or protocol that defines how much the price is on any given day. Use that in your code.

Comment: Also check out this article about the effect of number of columns and database engine on performance: https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/09/28/how-number-of-columns-affects-performance/

Comment: @Adelphia You have two options: store the price or store the algorithm because **both** can change over time. I would always store the price

Comment: That's a logical fallacy, Rufio. The algorithm changes, *causing* the price to change. Therefore there is no advantage to saving 365 prices versus one formula.

Comment: You made a good point though,  when it changes,  wouldn't you rather change one algorithm instead of 365 rows in a table. ..

Answer (score 6):

You should create a table with 6 columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS priceHistory (
    `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `date` datetime,
    `productId` VARCHAR(50),
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `createdAt` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Now you can insert the date and price for every day, the columns `created_at`, `updatedAt` and `id` are automatically inserted (and `updatedAt` automatically updated), so you don't need to bother for them any more.

If  you are saving those prices on a daily base and access the data later, you don't even need the `date` column, just use `createdAt` which, again, is automatically created on `INSERT`.

Once you have data, you can query for it like

```
SELECT * FROM priceHistory WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2015-02-29';
```

You might also find [mysql's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) on DATE functions usefull.

Edit

As @murenik mentioned in his answer, the recomended way would be to create a relation to the table holding your product details, which you might have. To do this, change the `productId` statement to

```
productId INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES products(id),
```

This will link those tables, making future queries easier and more effective.

```
SELECT ph.*, p.* 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN priceHistory ph on p.id = ph.productId
```

See mysql [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Comment: why not store the history of the algorithm instead.. just sayin.. it's cheaper

Comment: it is preferred to use snake_case as column name instead of camelCase

Answer (score 2):

The classic solution would be to use a junction table, with a price per product per date:

```
CREATE TABLE product_prices (
    product_id INT REFERENCES products(id),
    price DECIMAL (5, 2),
    date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, date)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

We had a complex rate table at one place I worked, and instead of storing the rate for each day, we stored the rate on the first day it changed. So if Unit1 (of a motel for example) was $50 a night from January to April, then $65 a night over the summer during tourist season, then back to $50 a night in the fall, the rate table would have 3 records:

```
Start Date         Close Date            Unit #   Rate
------------       -----------------     -------  -------
January 1, 2015    March 30, 2015        Unit1    $50
April 1, 2015      September 30, 2015    Unit1    $65
October 1, 2015    December 21, 2015     Unit1    $50
```

Then all you would need to do is find a rate record where your chosen date falls between the start and end date.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you are right i do need someting like this, but i didnt understand how to make the database in your answer, can you tell me more specific?

Comment: The table that we used was basically the example above, but with a unique identifier column as well. Most of the handling of rates was done with code. As the rate table was saved, we would track the last start date, and next start date of a rate change so that we could calculate the close date as we went. The very last rate automatically got an end date of Dec 31, 2099. We used a grid control (this was all in PC Software, not web software too) to build the rates and the code just went along row by row to save them back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

just make a table for

```
id of the product | date | price
```

Comment: but in this way there will be 365 datas for every product right? doesn't this make database so big?

Comment: Nope. Databases can perform very well even with millions of records.

Comment: @RecreatioN - this is not the ideal solution, but 365 rows in a table is tiny when you consider that facebook has databases with hundreds of millions of rows

Comment: A database table will perform worse the more columns it has actually. It is better to query a table with millions of rows and a few columns versus a table with hundreds of thousands of rows and nearly 400 columns.

Comment: i understand, thank you very much for your answer so it is not good to create 365 colums.

Comment: Consider going with Michael's answer. He has laid out a logical table structure and explained how it works. His structure will be much easier to update and maintain.

Comment: @Adelphia do you know what the ideal solution is?

Comment: @RecreationN yea, the ideal solution is the one I posted in my other comment. How do you determine the price for each item? What's the formula?